# Multiple array Id's, how?

Tags: php, arrays, uploader

I'm trying to make two image upload boxes inside custom posts which will be shown in a widget like

team 1 logo - team 1 name - team 1 score vs team 2 score - team 2 name - team logo.

These two upload boxes for two logos (team 1 and team2) appear- The first one works fine,  but in the second one, the image gets uploaded to the first box.

If I manually add a link to the second it works, but I need an option to upload the image to the second box as well. I need to somehow make it so that it accepts two id's for the same thing, because i think that's the issue as they both have 'type' => 'upload',

I'v added only for one, but i dont know how inside this code http://pastebin.com/JyT8mnS1 to change it so it can accept image uploader for both arrays.

My code is

```
array(
        'name' => 'Home Team Logo',
        'desc' => 'Chose Home Team Logo',
        'label'       => 'Images',
        'id' =>  'teamlogo1',
        'type' => 'upload',
        'std' => 'Browse',
        'class' =>'upload_image_button'

    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Away Team Logo',
        'desc' => 'Chose Away Team Logo',
        'label'       => 'Images',
        'id' =>  'teamlogo2',
        'type' => 'upload',
        'std' => 'Browse',
        'class' =>'upload_image_button'

    ),
```

If needed my javascript code is this http://pastebin.com/RG4YASuj

Just to inform you I'm completly newbie with this, so i would prefer some example from which i could learn more and actually make it work.

Comment: Um, don't really understand the question. Replicating and sharing the issue ina JSFiddle will greatly improve your chances of getting a correct answer

Comment: use a ` foreach ( $your_files as $file) `  to loop over the uploaded files?

Comment: How about using a modal to upload images and css the modal based on the user's choice, home team or away team.

Comment: Hey Seler JSFiddle actually wont show it properly as this code is placed inside my function.php and on JSFiddle it's only html  @Kevin Seifert I'v updated the question, can you show that in a example so i can figure it out better  mdamia users (me) would need to upload both inside custom post so with css is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

HI you form should be like this:userfile[] is creating an array of images

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: i updated the question, perhaps it will explain better, but if understand you correctly i would have to replace what's inside case upload under echo with this file? If that's true what then with javascript which actually calls this?